# What can I do, client-side, to check if someone is hacking my website?

Tags: javascript, xss

For instance, are there common fingerprints of XSS that, if an XSS is occurring, a JavaScript script could detect it? Or detect other tampering?

Comment: You want to employ "anti hacking" measure *client-side*, the side that is under control of the attacker? Yeah... no. What's wrong with using well established XSS prevention techniques?

Comment: Maybe I don't have access to the server side of this page. deceze you should not be so fast to criticize when you don't know what somebody is doing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just pointing out the *obvious* flaws. If your scheme can't stand up to a little criticism you shouldn't use it. *Why* you're trying to do something doesn't change its flaws.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could scan every anchor tag and check to see if a sessionId was attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Content Security Policy. It's not supported in IE, but works in Safari/Chrome/Firefox/Opera.

You could set it up in report-only mode, and whitelist any scripts, stylesheets etc. you allow. May not be applicable though if you are using a lot of inline scripting etc.